# No GUI and no internet after rebooting

Tags: 18.04, xorg, internet, gui

I rebooted my machine and there is clearly something very wrong. There is no GUI and there is a black screen after running `startx`.

`lsb_release` returns:

```
command not found
```

`apt-get update` returns many "Failed to fetch https..." errors

I don't seem to have internet connection, so I cannot reinstall X, for example. This is on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Can you give more details? What did you do before restarting? Did you install or remove anything, for example?

Comment: I installed a python package rpy2 by running sudo apt-get install python3-rpy2 python-rpy2. Then the python module was installed for python3.6 and not 3.7. So I tried removing python3.6 by running sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.6. Then rerun sudo apt-get install python3-rpy2 python-rpy2, which made everything work except after I rebooted.

Comment: When you removes python3.7 you might have removed much more. Try reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop package.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because I don't seem to have working internet connection. Is there another solution?

Comment: I never tried it myself, but it should be possible to reinstall offline: https://www.maketecheasier.com/update-upgrade-ubuntu-without-internet-connection/ or simply reinstall Ubuntu over your original install. Might be simpler and quicker.

Answer (score 1):

when grub appears press e (for edit), go to the row starting with linux and add

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

after ro

example

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-32-generic root=UUID=0a863c27-4a96-48db-aac1-1566522402d1 ro  systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

from me. This start a text mode.

check with

```
tail -n30 /var/log/apt/history.log
```

what you have removed or installed at last.

Install the removed packages and remove the installed packages.
and install like @To Do wrote 
The ubuntu-desktop anew.

```
sudo  apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell
```

I hope I did not explain to complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to fix it in recovery mode.

- Start from a switched of computer
- Press Esc once when the logo of your computer disappears.
- You should get the option to start ubuntu or go to advanced mode
- in advanced mode you can choose a kernel in recovery mode. Just pick one
- choose to start network (use a cable connection)
- choose root - try

  ```
  apt update
  ```
- If that doesn't work

  ```
  ping 8.8.8.8
  ```
- If that works, you have a nameserver problem.

  ```
  nano /etc/resolv.conf
  ```

  and add

  ```
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  ```

From now you should be able to

```
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell
```

and

```
reboot
```

The nameserver you added will be replaced by what it should be after reboot (/etc/resolv.conf will be overwritten). So if you want to go back to recovery mode, you might have to add a nameserver of your choice again.